# I need to create a PDF file and inside the PDF file I need to give table with rows and columns using MigraDoc PDFsharp NuGet packages

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, migradoc

I want to add tables, rows, columns to my PDF. Can you suggest any coding for creating PDF file and also I need to add logo to my header part. I need a PDF with 6 pages with required footer and within the PDF I need to give my complete data in the form of a table with rows and columns and also I need to adjust the alignments also all these to be done with the help of MigraDoc and PDFsharp NuGet packages in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The samples "Invoice" and "Hello MigraDoc" show how to create tables, headers, footers.

Official site:
https://pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDocSamples.ashx

Samples on GitHub:
https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp.Samples